# FCM registration token send twice

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my first time trying firebase with nextjs. even the first time using firebase. In my project, I want to use Firebase's cloud messaging feature to display a notification. however when I try to send currentToken to console.log the token is sent twice. and the result is that when I send a message from the Firebase console the message is sent twice but only the first message has content and the next one shows the words "background message title" and "background message body". I think there is no problem as long as my message is sent. However, if notification permission has not been given to the page and the notification has just been permitted, the token will not only be sent twice, but the token sent will also be different.

this is my code

```
"use client"
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging,getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

export default function Home() {
  const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "<secret>",
      authDomain: "<secret>",
      projectId: "<secret>",
      storageBucket: "<secret>",
      messagingSenderId: "<secret>",
      appId: "<secret>",
      measurementId: "<secret>"
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const messaging = getMessaging(app);

  useEffect(() => {
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
      if (permission === 'granted') {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: '<myVapidKey>' }).then((currentToken) => {
          if (currentToken) {
              console.log('congratulation this is your token:', currentToken);
          } else {
              console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        });
      } else {
          console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
          alert('Unable to get permission to notify.');
      }
    });
  },[])

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
     <div><h1>test</h1></div>
    </main>
  )
}
```